# Change of basis matrix exactly one row away from being correct

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization, change-of-basis, hermitian-matrices

For homework, I'm given a matrix
$$
A =
\begin{bmatrix}
3 & 2i & -2i\\
-2i & 0 & -1\\
2i & -1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
in an hermitian space. We are trying to find an orthonormal basis from there.

So far, I've found the eigenvalues which are $-1$ and $5$ as well as the eigenspaces
$$
E_{-1} = \langle \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
1 \\
1
\end{bmatrix}
;
\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}
\begin{bmatrix}
-i \\
1 \\
-1
\end{bmatrix}
\rangle
$$
and
$$
E_5 = \langle \frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}
\begin{bmatrix}
2i \\
1 \\
-1
\end{bmatrix}
\rangle
$$
Put together, we obtain a matrix
$$
P =
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & \frac{-i}{\sqrt3} & \frac{2i}{\sqrt6} \\
\frac{1}{\sqrt2} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt6} \\
\frac{1}{\sqrt2} & \frac{-1}{\sqrt{3}} & \frac{-1}{\sqrt6}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $P^T \cdot A \cdot \overline{P} = S$ should give us $S$, a diagonal matrix made of eigenvalues. However, it seems that
$$
P' =
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & \frac{i}{\sqrt3} & \frac{-2i}{\sqrt6} \\
\frac{1}{\sqrt2} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt6} \\
\frac{1}{\sqrt2} & \frac{-1}{\sqrt{3}} & \frac{-1}{\sqrt6}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
which is the matrix $P$ where the first row has been multiplied by $(-1)$ is actually the expected result. I can't figure out where this $(-1)$ comes from however.

Comment: By $P^T$ do you mean the transpose or the conjugate transpose?

Comment: @Marcel That would be the regular transpose

Comment: Try using the conjugate transpose

Comment: @Marcel It still doesn't give me a diagonal matrix I'm afraid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need $P^{-1}AP$ in order to get a diagonal matrix.

If $P$ is unitary, then $P^{-1}=P^\dagger$, the transpose conjugated.

But $P$ will only be unitary if the eigenvectors are orthonormal.

Actually I just implemented your $P$ in Maple and it really works, so you must be making some really simple mistake.

Comment: Seems like I confused some of my matrices. To add on to this, for $A$ in an hermitian space, there exists, thanks to the spectral theorem, a matrix $P$ where $P^{-1}AP = S$. However, this also means that there exists $P'$ where $P' = \overline{P}$ so that $(P')^TA\overline{P'} = S$. So there seems to be two ways to compute $S$. The exercise probably didn't want me to use $P$ as I would need to calculate the inverse $P^{-1}$ instead of calculating the transpose and the conjugate of $P'$ which is faster.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. If you are conjugating the equation, then do not forget that $\bar{A}\neq A$.

Comment: Basically, $P = \overline{P'}$. Moreover, $P^{-1}AP = S = (P')^TA\overline{P'}$

Comment: I do not see how you have two ways of computing $S$. They are the same.

Comment: Yes, one expression can be obtained from the other using what we know about hermitian spaces. However, practically speaking, in one case, you have to compute the inverse of a matrix whereas in the other case, you just have to compute the conjugate and the transpose.